# Looping through list in c# with data from informix

Tags: c#, informix

```
 var listprocedures = Ix.GetConnection
            .Query(@"SELECT PROCNAME FROM SYSPROCEDURES WHERE PROCNAME LIKE 'web_%'")
            .ToList();
foreach (var procName in listprocedures)
```

Where i am making mistake and cant do the foreach through all procedure names that i have in listprocedures.
Listprocedures is good populated with data, but in foreach it gives me error that the first item in Listprocedures is null...

Comment: Have you debugged and checked the first item?

Comment: Whats the value of first item

Comment: [0] {{DapperRow, procname = 'web_insert_nalog'}}

This is the value of the first item

Comment: What is the error and what is the type of the item in the list? Is that a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done it this way

```
 var procedureNames = Ix.GetConnection.Query(@"SELECT PROCNAME FROM SYSPROCEDURES WHERE PROCNAME LIKE 'web_%'");
     foreach (IDictionary<string, object> row in procedureNames)
                    {

                        foreach (var procName in row)
```